# Is electromagnetism created by charged particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-fields

From what I am able to understand, electromagnetism is a force that raised from electric and magnetic fields. And what I gathered from Maxwell's equation is electric and magnetic fields are basically the same thing (electric fields are created by a charge or a magnetic field and magnetic fields are created by an electric current) and magnetism is produce by moving electric charges. So does that mean that electromagnetism arises due to charged particles? I could just be intrepreting this wrong due to my struggles in physics.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, more or less. But this does not magneticc fields (or electric fields for that matter) *are* charged particles.

Answer (score 2):

Electromagnetic waves, also known as light, can exist without any charged particles at all. You could imagine a universe where there is no matter at all, but there are still electromagnetic fields due to light waves bouncing around.

In our universe, however, pretty much all electromagnetism around is due to charged particles. Sometimes the fields travel very far away from the particles that produced them, such as sunlight. Other than light, most of the electromagnetism you experience (fridge magnets, power lines, cell phones) happens very close to the charged particles it comes from.

I'm not sure if we have any way to know whether or not there are primordial photons left over from the Big Bang that weren't originally produced by any charged particle. (In fact, this idea may not even make sense, since it's not always clear whether two photons at different times and places are "the same" photon.) Does anyone have thoughts on this?

Comment: Oh I thought EM Radiation was caused or at least influenced by the acceleration of charged particles?

Comment: Yes, "electromagnetic radiation" and "light" and "photons" all refer to the same thing. This is what I'm asking in the last part of the answer: As far as I know all of the light in our universe probably comes from charged particles, but in principle there could be some light that was already there at the beginning of time.